# Firebase Database InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I´m getting this error when I try to write an object into Firebase Database, the error is the following:

`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zzaE(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzaw(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzav(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
```

The error started when I tried to add the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP from Firebase, guided by the example from Udacity, here´s my POJO:

```
public class Messages {

    private String content, author, authorPhoto;
    private int type;
    protected HashMap<String, Object> timeStampCreated;
    private Uri uri;


    public Messages() {//Empty default constructor, necessary for FireBase to be able to deserialize blog posts
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getAuthorPhoto() {
        return authorPhoto;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return (long)timeStampCreated.get("timeStamp");
    }

    public void setTimeStamp() {
        HashMap<String, Object> hmDate = new HashMap<>();
        hmDate.put("timeStamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        this.timeStampCreated = hmDate;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setAuthorPhoto(String authorPhoto) {
        this.authorPhoto = authorPhoto;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

and here´s the method where I´m trying to add this Messages object to Firebase Database, the exact error is when I set the value:

```
public void sendMessage(String content, final int type) {
        Messages message = new Messages();
        message.setContent(content);
        message.setTimeStamp();
        message.setAuthor(email);
        message.setAuthorPhoto(picURL);
        message.setType(type);

        FBRefMessages.push().setValue(message, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.d("Adapter", "onChildAdded: The adapter is: " + mAdapter);
                    updateNodes();
                } else {//There was an error
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Uri is not a supported data type, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/understanding-data.html

Try replace it with String.

Comment: I fixed that but I did not work, I add a breakpoint on this line: FBRefMessages.push().setValue(message, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() , and I dont know why but the reference is setting to this value: No such instance field: 'FBRefMessages'

Comment: I have tried to remove `getTimeStamp` with the `JsonIgnore` , and It worked, but I need to add the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, how can I add that?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this for a while and concluded that it is not possible to use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in a POJO the way you would like.

As you may know, `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a `Map<String,String>`.  In the non-POJO use case, you can supply it as an `Object` argument to `setValue()` or as an element of a `Map<String,Object>` for `setValue()`.  When processing the data store request, the Firebase server recognizes the special marker value and replaces it with the server time.  When the data is subsequently read, it is returned as a `Long`.

The POJO processing for serialization is based on a field having a fixed type.  I don't see how it can be made to work for a field that needs to be a `Map<String,String>` on output and a `Long` on input.

If you can tolerate less accurate timestamps, you might consider adding a listener to monitor the clock skew and deriving your own timestamps from it.  This is described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew).

Comment: so theres no workaround that would help me use the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Maybe you will get another answer from someone more clever than I am.  I  don't see a way to use it in a POJO the way you want. An alternative is to store the creation time as a separate value, outside your `Messages` POJO. If the calls to setValue() are made together, the timestamp should be accurate to within a second.